# Where is the merge function for CiviMail located in code?

Tags: civimail, civisms

CiviMail has a great feature that finds intended recipients with the same email address prior to a mailing and prevents multiple emails getting sent to the same address.  It seems similar to the Merge Address or Merge Household features in the Export action. **Where in the code base is the CiviMail merge functionality located?**

I'd like to create a similar function for CiviSMS and am looking for a starting point.

Based on the merge functions I've found in Export (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Export/BAO/Export.php), I've tried a few different searches on GitHub for the CiviMail merge function like "mergeemail" or "merge_email" but can't find anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think the dirty work is done here in a sql statement using a group by clause. I don't know the code base at all however. I am on win7 and use the grepWin program.

..\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Mailing\BAO\Mailing.php

Line 558

```
  // CRM-3975
  $groupBy = $groupJoin = '';
  if ($dedupeEmail) {
    $groupJoin = " INNER JOIN civicrm_email e ON e.id = i.email_id";
    $groupBy = " GROUP BY e.email ";
  }
```

CiviMail should have the option of not sending duplicate emails
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-3975